# What's wrong with raw_input() (EOFError: EOF when reading a line)

Tags: python

I am using python 2.7.6, and when calling `raw_input()`, there is an exception:

```
flight_name = raw_input('\nEnter the name of Flight: ')
```

I found the solution, but why there appears such exception? Is it a bag?

```
try:
      flight_name = raw_input('\nEnter the name of Flight: ')
except (EOFError):
      break
```

Comment: What input are you providing to `raw_input`? Can you post full stack trace?

Comment: I input some name of flight, for example 'London-Paris', and then look through the names of my flights and check if it equals to smth

Comment: @user3238724, are you using sublime or something similar? see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758782/python-eoferror-eof-when-reading-a-line

Comment: @Litwisha: same base cause then; your IDE console doesn't support input.

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
sys.stdin = open('/dev/tty')
answer = raw_input('Commit anyway? [N/y] ')
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7437724/1465640

Comment: No you can't, not in the PyCharm IDE console. This only works if you are *already* in a terminal but `stdin` is a pipe.

Comment: The question doesn't mention anything about PyCharm. If a user searches for `raw_input + EOFError`, as I did, he will find this question. Yes, buried in the comments there is a line mentioning PyCharm, but as long as the question doesn't say anything about PyCharm this is a valid answer.

Comment: Without that comment the question is too vague to answer, and I'm pondering closing it; the alternative is that we edit that detail in. Even if this wasn't just about an IDE, setting `sys.stdin` to `/dev/tty` only works if there *is* a TTY to connect to, and if `stdin` isn't already connected to a TTY.

Answer (score 2):

This answer

```
sys.stdin = open('/dev/tty')
answer = raw_input('Commit anyway? [N/y] ')
```

is useful if you've previously read from sys.stdin in your code.  In that case, the raw_input line will throw the EOF error without waiting for user input, if you set the sys.stdin = open('/dev/tty') just before raw_input, it resets the stdin and allows the user input to work. (tested in python 2.7) with

```
## test.py
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
  pass
#sys.stdin = open('/dev/tty')
raw_input("Are you sure?")
```

**echo 'abc' | python test.py**

Which raises:

**EOFError: EOF when reading a line**

Until you uncomment the 2nd to last line.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read something from standard input but you're not getting anything, only the EOF. This actually lets you know the user is not providing any input and you can do other things for this condition.

Comment: But I actually input some name of  flight. Why it doesn't work?

Comment: How do you input the name of the flight? Which keys are you using?

Comment: For example London-Paris